# How the LMA(License Management Application) works in Salesforce?

Tags: lma

My client wants to use LMA Application in Salesforce Application and i have found that is used for creating leads and licence offering for customer installation.But i think that LMA installs only in partner org and i dont have access of my client Partner org.Can anyone describe the whole procedure process that how its works.

Answer (score 11):

The LMA has documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_lma.meta/workbook_lma/lma_intro.htm). There's a lot of reading material to go over, but basically it is pretty straight forward. You request an installation link to the package, you install the package into your business org (note: definitely *not* in a Developer Edition org), connect the app to your package, and finally configure any workflow rules or processes you want to define, such as follow up emails after installing, renewal reminders, and even uninstall notifications for exit surveys. The installation itself only takes a few minutes, like most other AppExchange apps.

Once installed, when a person goes to your listing on the AppExchange, they may Try It Now (if configured) or install it into a sandbox or developer edition org. If so, you'll get a new Lead from their trial experience, including name, organization name, and email. If they install the package into a production org, you'll also get a License, which allows you to configure trial mode, an expiration date for the trial, and the number of licenses issued (or Site-wide, to allow unlimited licenses).

Finally, using LMA, you can log in to a Subscriber's org to troubleshoot issues, the same way technical support can log in to a client's org. Subscribers must grant login access, and no username or passwords need to be shared with the ISV. You can even get debug logs that contain additional managed package logging details that are normally hidden from subscribers, which can help pinpoint an error in your code.

I recommend that you read the LMA documentation for more information.